# QCAR cannot be resolved

Tags: wikitude

I download the wikitude sdk and tried the SimpleIRExample project but in this codes

private class VuforiaServiceImplementation implements VuforiaInterface{

```
    @Override
    public void deInit() {
        QCAR.deinit();
    }

    @Override
    public int init() {
        return QCAR.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        QCAR.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        QCAR.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(int width, int height) {
        QCAR.onSurfaceChanged(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated() {
        QCAR.onSurfaceCreated();
    }

    @Override
    public void setInitParameters(Activity activity, int nFlags) {
        QCAR.setInitParameters(activity, nFlags);
    }

}
```

QCAR is having a redline and the error is QCAR cannot be resolved. please do help me with this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are basically missing the QCAR library. Have a look at http://forum.wikitude.com/home/-/message_boards/message/153377